# HTML5 Server-Sent Events : empty response

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, server-sent-events

I am writing a web service using PHP (CodeIgniter).
I tried to follow several basic tutorials on Server-Sent Events in HTML5.

However, I wasn't able to run any of them. 
I am receiving proper headers, as expected (every 3 seconds), but I don't receive any data.

Could it be a WAMP configuration or CodeIgniter problem?

The code of the controller method:

```
public function sse() {
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        $time = date('r');
        echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
        flush();
    }
```

The code of the view (partially):

```
<div id="play"> msg </div>

<script>
    var source = new EventSource("<?php echo site_url('play/sse') ?>");
    source.onmessage=function(event) {
        document.getElementById("play").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
    };
</script>
```

HTTP headers :

```
Request URL:http://localhost/index.php/play/sse
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/event-stream
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: ...
```

Comment: According to the headers you are showing, you have a response. Are you sure there is no data in it?

Comment: In the Chrome 'Firebug' I've got "This request has no response data available." and onmessage function is never actually called. Do i miss something and in fact could I be receiving the data?

Comment: @mechu, I have perfectly the same issue. `onmessage` is not fired and the data is always empty, even if when I manually enter the file, it's not. I have no idea what's going on... (PS: Też z Polski)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it by replacing the single quotes with double quote in header and in response/results.

```
   header("Content-type: text/event-stream");
   header("Connection: Keep-alive");
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
   echo "retry:1000\n";
   $result = "data:".json_encode($result)."\n\n";
```